# Previous and Next button for a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm creating some 10 HTML pages in my website. I would like to have a previous and next navigation button/link in all pages.so how can we get this?

Comment: `<p>Read the <a href="1.html" rel=prev>Previous</a> or <a href="3.html" rel=next>Next</a> page.</p>`

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to keep track of your previous and next page

Comment: What did you try exactly? How are your html pages accessed?

Comment: @DoanCuong — Cookies? Why would the information need to persist?

Comment: Oh, maybe I was misunderstood his question. I thought he want to do something similar to `undo` and `redo`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If yours is a Static Website with just 10 pages to navigate two and fro, Add the manual navigation links.

```
<a href="prev-page.html"> Previous Page </a> 
<a href="next-page.html"> Next Page </a>
```

However if its not static there are many Pagination scripts that can be handy. just Google it.

Answer (score 4):

Since your question not clear, Let me assume you have 10 static html pages.

now u just add the following code in all pages

```
<input type="button" name="b1" value="prev" onclick="location.href='pre_page.html'">
<input type="button" name="b2" value="next" onclick="location.href='next_page.html'">
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please explain your requirements in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the below for your static HTML pages.

```
<a href="xxx.html">Back</a>|<a href="xxx.html">Next</a>
```

You have to manually put the html links on your individual pages that you want to show as previous or next for those individual pages.